# Unknown DAV provider: svn

Tags: centos, subversion

I did something wrong

On my CentOS 5.9, I did the following:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build rewrite_confs
```

But now I get an error restarting httpd:

```
[root@1332 conf]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 213 of /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/httpd.conf:
Unknown DAV provider: svn
```

@line 213, there is something like:

```
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/svn/
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Dytech Solutions Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My guess is that my DirectAdmin is automatically writing them locale httpd.conf files.
And I messed up the SVN repositories somehow...

I'm also guessing that it has to do something with an alternative apache config due to autobuild so the module isn't loaded normally.

I found [this link](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL)

Where its states that:

First, your httpd.conf needs to load the mod_dav_svn module.
      If you pass --enable-mod-activation to Subversion's configure,
      'make install' target should automatically add this line for you.
      In any case, if Apache HTTPD gives you an error like "Unknown
      DAV provider: svn", then you may want to verify that this line
      exists in your httpd.conf:

```
     LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

But I'm afraid to break even more stuff

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Is this line commented out in your httpd.conf like so?

Commented:

`#LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so`

Uncommented:

`LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so`

If it is, uncomment it and restart apache. Hope you've already fixed it.

Comment: I had a similar problem and with Ubuntu 20.04 I had to (1) provide the directive in file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.load` and (2) make sure I had the necessary symbolic links (`ln -s`) in the directory `etc/apache2/mods-enabled` to the following files in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`: `dav_svn.conf`, `dav_svn.load`, `dav_fs.conf`, `dav_fs.load`, and `dav.load`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299877/unknown-dav-provider-svn-when-starting-up-apache-web-server-with-subversion-s/1300074#1300074